# How convert a List<Dictionary<string, object>> to a List<string> of each item's "name" property in a lambda?

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I have a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` with values like this:

```
{ name: "Joe", age: 23, ... },
{ name: "Jack", age: 19, ... },
...
```

I want to create a `List<string>` from that which holds the names.

How would I do this (along with the cast)?

I know how to select out the values by name, but how do I use a lambda to return the `name` field and cast it to string for the list?

Is this right?

```
List<string> names = objects.Select(
    item => item[ "name" ].ToString()
).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: Why don't you try it.

Comment: Seems it's OK. `ToString()` method in this line: `tem[ "name" ].ToString()` is redundant.

Comment: @MaciejLos its necessary because OP's dictionary has objects as values, not strings, so you have to convert or cast it.

Comment: It would be nice if you included a few lines that loaded sample data into the `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`

Comment: You state that the **Values** look like: `{ name: "Joe", age: 23, ... }`. But later you reference the **Key** with the string `"name"`. Which are keys and what do the values look like?

Answer (score 5):

See if this works:

```
var names = objects.Select(item => (string)item["name"]).ToList();
```

However, if I may make a suggestion, you shouldn't use Dictionaries this way. Consider making a class for the data you have in your Dictionary.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

Comment: I'm not "using" dictionaries that way, it's what's returned to me from another library after a request for data from the database. It represents the rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

Since the values are stored in a dictionary the key might not necessarily exist. To guard against [`KeyNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception.aspx) use [`Dictionary(TKey, TValue).TryGetValue(TKey, TValue)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx).

```
var objects = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"name", "Foo"}
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"name", "Bar"}
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"blah", "Baz"}
    }
};

// C# Local function
IEnumerable<string> GetName(IDictionary<string, object> obj)
{
    // C# 7 out variable
    if (obj.TryGetValue("name", out var name))
    {
        yield return name as string;
    }
}

// ["Foo", "Bar"]
var names =
    objects
        .SelectMany(GetName)
        .ToList();
```